# ECMAScript not running

Tags: javascript

I am two days into learning JavaScript and I unable make the script below run, any corrections?

```js
const list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    list[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        list[i].textcontent = list[i].textcontent.toUppercase;
    });
    list[i].addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        list[i].textcontent = list[i].textcontent.toLowercase;
    });
}
```

Comment: @AdamMcquiff the code should be **here**, possibly in a stack snippet.

Comment: @Pointy cool...

Comment: Maybe those articles can help you to ask better questions :) [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```js
const list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    list[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        list[i].textContent = list[i].textContent.toUpperCase();
    });
    list[i].addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        list[i].textContent = list[i].textContent.toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>
```

The only problem with your code is case typos (`textContent`) and absense of function invokations + typos (`toLowerCase()`).

Comment: Still no difference.

Comment: Make an example at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

That´s not an good Example for arrow functions

this work´s:

```
    const list=document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i ++){
        list[i].onmouseover = () => list[i].textContent=list[i].textContent.toUpperCase();
        list[i].onmouseout = () => list[i].textContent=list[i].textContent.toLowerCase();
    }
```